# Guardar datos de un array a base de datos mysql mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Mi problema es que, quiero guardar unos datos guardados en un `JSON` a mi tabla en la base de datos de `MYSQL`, pero al momento de leer los datos todos me los muestra en 0 y así con ese valor los guarda en la base.

Esta es la función en javascript para poder guardar los datos

```
function Guardar(val) {
    var inciso = val;

    
    var sub = document.getElementById("SUBTOTAL");
    var SUBTOTAL = sub.innerHTML;
    var isv = document.getElementById("IMPUESTO");
    var IMPUESTO = isv.innerHTML;
    var tot = document.getElementById("TOTAL");
    var TOTAL = tot.innerHTML;

    var datos = [];
    
//datos traidos desde una tabla
    var rows = document.getElementById('datos').rows;

    for (var a = 0; a < rows.length; a++) 
    {
//este es el arreglo donde estan todos los datos
        datos.push([{
            IDPRODUCTO: rows[a].cells[0].innerHTML, PRECIO: rows[a].cells[3].innerHTML, CANTIDAD: rows[a].cells[2].innerHTML, SUBTOTAL: SUBTOTAL,
            IMPUESTO: IMPUESTO, TOTAL: TOTAL
        }]);

    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Factura/GuardarFactura',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
        success: async function (data) {
            if (data != false) {
                $('#info').show();

            }
            else {
                //toastr.info('No se pudo guardar el registro');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Este es el controlador

```
public JsonResult GuardarFactura(int IDPRODUCTO, double PRECIO, int CANTIDAD, double SUBTOTAL, double IMPUESTO, double TOTAL)
{

    List<USU_USUARIO> lista = new List<USU_USUARIO>();
    USU_USUARIO usu_usuario = new USU_USUARIO();
    var DatosUsuario = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<USU_USUARIO>("USU_USUARIO");
    if (DatosUsuario == null)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }

    USU_USUARIO usuario = DatosUsuario;
    var idusuario = usuario.IDUSUARIO;

//llamado del metodo 
    var retorno = new object();
    FAC_DETALLE_FACTURA fac_detalle_factura = new FAC_DETALLE_FACTURA();
    retorno = fac_detalle_factura.GuardarFactura(IDPRODUCTO, PRECIO, CANTIDAD, SUBTOTAL, IMPUESTO, TOTAL, idusuario);

    return Json(retorno);
}
```

Este es el metodo donde hace el llamado del procedimiento almacenado para poder guardar los datos

```
public bool GuardarFactura(int IDPRODUCTO, double PRECIO, int CANTIDAD, double SUBTOTAL, double IMPUESTO,  
    double TOTAL, string IDUSUARIO)
{
    try
    {
        this.Conectar();

        com = new MySqlCommand("REGISTRAR_FACTURA", this.cadena);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDPRODUCTO", IDPRODUCTO);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRECIO", PRECIO);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CANTIDAD", CANTIDAD);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUBTOTAL", SUBTOTAL);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMPUESTO", IMPUESTO);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOTAL", TOTAL);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDUSUARIO", IDUSUARIO);


        return Convert.ToBoolean(com.ExecuteNonQuery());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Desconectar();
    }
}
```

Procedimiento almacenado para poder guardar los datos de la factura

```
CREATE DEFINER=`developer`@`%` PROCEDURE `REGISTRAR_FACTURA`(
IN IDPRODUCTO INT,
IN PRECIO double,
IN CANTIDAD INT,
IN SUBTOTAL DOUBLE,
IN IMPUESTO DOUBLE,
IN TOTAL DOUBLE,
IN IDUSUARIO varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO FAC_FACTURA( FECHA_EMISION)
VALUES (now());

INSERT INTO FAC_DETALLE_FACTURA(IDFACTURA, IDPRODUCTO, PRECIO, CANTIDAD, SUBTOTAL, IMPUESTO, TOTAL, IDUSUARIO)
VALUES ((select IDFACTURA from FAC_FACTURA ORDER BY FECHA_EMISION DESC limit 1), IDPRODUCTO,  PRECIO, CANTIDAD, SUBTOTAL,
       IMPUESTO, TOTAL, IDUSUARIO);
       

END
```

Tabla donde se quieren guardar los datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi es como los muestra y asi se guardan en la base de datos tambien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces no sé cuál es mi problema, porque los datos se muestran bien en el array si los muestro con console.log
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Podrías incluir en tu pregunta la salida de log que mencionas al final? Sospecho que son los tipos de datos, es para verificar y escribir una respuesta.

Comment: esta bien, ya esta

Comment: Tu problema es pensar que c# recibe cada item de un json en un post por separado... tu metodo recibe un objeto que tiene la misma forma del json.. en base a eso, c# lo parsea automaticamente, y ahi vas a tener toda la info que vos queres...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios errores, intentaré explicar paso a paso:

###### 1.- Estás enviando por `Post`, entonces a tu `action` le falta el `[HttpPost]`

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GuardarFactura(int IDPRODUCTO, double PRECIO, int CANTIDAD, double SUBTOTAL, double IMPUESTO, double TOTAL)
 {

 }
```

<sub>Nota: Esto sigue estando incorrecto, leer a continuación</sub>

###### 2.- Uso del `JSON.stringify(datos)`

Esto convierte un objeto en un string (JSON), entonces finalmente lo que envías no es un objeto es un string que representa dicho objeto. Ahora piensa lo que pasaría si tu realmente quisieras enviar un `string`, como lo diferencias de un string/json de uno normal??.- Respuesta: Con `contentType`, y es lo que te falta agregar

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //<--ESTO
        url: '/Home/GuardarFactura',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
```

###### 3.- Envío de una colección de elementos

Tu `action/controller` recibe múltiples parámetros de **UN** objeto, pero lo que tu estas enviando es un `array` de objetos, por lo tanto debes preparar el `action/controller` para que sea capaz de recibir esto.

Lo primero es crear una clase

```
public class Datos
{
    public int IDPRODUCTO { get; set; }
    public double PRECIO { get; set; }
    public int CANTIDAD { get; set; }
    public double SUBTOTAL { get; set; }
    public double IMPUESTO { get; set; }
    public double TOTAL { get; set; }
}
```

Y luego en tu `action/controller`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GuardarFactura(Datos[] datos)
{

}
```

<sub>Nota: Esto sigue estando incorrecto, leer a continuación</sub>

###### 4.- Ubicación de los datos utiles.

Cuando envías los datos al servidor estos pueden estar en varias ubicaciones (en la url, en el body, en el form). Así como está configurado el `$.ajax` te está enviando los datos en el `Body`, pero en ASP MVC (cuando **NO** está configurado como API, si no que como web) espera recibir los datos en un `form` (el tipico form HTML), para indicar que se espera los datos del `body` debes usar `[FromBody]`, quedando el `action/controller` de esta manera:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GuardarFactura([FromBody]Datos[] datos)
{

}
```

Comment: Hey! gracias por tu respuesta, pero intente esto y no me funciono

Comment: @ivon El código lo probé y funciona. Dale otra vuelta

Comment: si, ya me lee el json en el controlador me sirvio, pero ahora como hago para poder guardar esos datos en la tabla de mi base de datos usando el mismo metodo que tengo? @Yussef

Comment: Ya lo pude hacer, me sirvio mucho tu respuesta. Gracias!! @Yussef